# How create polygons around points with specific area and without overlapping?

Tags: buffer, polygon, point, overlap, area

I have a layer of points and I want to draw a polygon around each point (similar to buffer or voronoid polygons functions do). However, polygons cannot overlap with each other (as often occurs with the buffer function) and all polygons need to have the same area (e.g. 100km2).

I have generated buffers without overlapping, but the area of the circles are 100km2 or less, and I could not find how specify a constrain in area.

Voronoid polygons are not a solution because some of these polygons have an area less than 100km2 and I could not find any option for "draw again" these polygons to achieve 100km2 area.

I look for a solution where each polygon is building taking into account the other polygons (to avoid overlapping), all polygons have the same area (100km2) and each polygon include inside one point. The result can contain any polygon shape and any position of the point inside the polygon.

Any ideas in R or QGIS?

Thank you,